# Alamofire JSON could not be serialized

Tags: php, ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to make a PHP Post request with Alamofire in my swift app, which has to send SMS with OVH api, but I got an issue :

`FAILURE: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6006 "JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length.}`

**I'm not finding how to see echos from the PHP script to solve it**. I think that it isn't an Alamofire problem because I make an other request to send emails and it works well. Here is my request where there is the error :

```
func sendSmsAutoRequest(completionHandler: (responseObject: NSDictionary?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let username = prefs.stringForKey(StorageManager.USER_NAME)!
    let messageText = prefs.stringForKey(StorageManager.MESSAGE_TEXT)!

    let parameters = ["contactsSms": contactsSms, "username": username, "messageText": messageText]
    request(.POST, "http://XXX/dontworry/sendAutoSms.php", parameters: (parameters as! [String : AnyObject])).responseJSON { response in
        print(response)
    }

}
```

and here is my script :

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use \Ovh\Api;

$applicationKey = "XXX";
$applicationSecret = "XXX";
$consumer_key = "XXX";

$endpoint = "ovh-eu";

$contactsSms = $_POST['contactsSms'];
$userName = $_POST['username'];
$messageText = $_POST['messageText'];

$conn = new Api($applicationKey,
                $applicationSecret,
                $endpoint,
                $consumer_key);

$smsServices = $conn->get('/sms/');

$content = (object) array(
                            "charset"=> "UTF-8",
                            "class"=> "phoneDisplay",
                            "coding"=> "7bit",
                            "message"=> $messageText,
                            "noStopClause"=> true,
                            "priority"=> "high",
                            "receivers"=> $contactsSms,
                            "senderForResponse"=> true,
                            "validityPeriod"=> 2880
                            );

$resultPostJob = $conn->post('/sms/'. $smsServices[0] . '/jobs/', $content);

$smsJobs = $conn->get('/sms/'. $smsServices[0] . '/jobs/');

echo '{"contacts": $contactsSms,"username": $username, "messageText": $messageText, "result": $resultPostJob, "sms": $smsJobs}'; ?>
```

EDIT : It seems to work, I don't have the error anymore ! But the SMS is not sent...

Comment: Try adding `parameters as! [String : AnyObject], encoding: .JSON)`.. Possibly, try `parameters as! [String : String], encoding: .JSON)` if you can

Comment: @senty - No, the response is JSON. But if you look at the PHP code, the web service is expecting is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request. Making the request JSON makes the situation worse.

Comment: Karz, helmbert correctly diagnosed one problem here. Build associative array and then `json_encode` it. Also note your PHP refers to `$userName` in input and `$username` in output (but never really use it?). If your SMS is still not going out, though, you need to diagnose what's going on. You are including `$contactsSms`, `$username`, and `$messageText` in the returned JSON, so how did that look? What was `$smsJobs`? Edit your question and show us what this `response.result.value` looked like.

Answer (score 3):

From a first reading, your PHP script most probably prints invalid JSON. The following statement will print JSON that contains unquoted strings (assuming one or more of the parameters like `$_POST['messsageText']` contain string values):

```
echo '{"contacts": $contactsSms,"username": $username, "messageText": $messageText, "result": $resultPostJob, "sms": $smsJobs}';
```

Example output (pretty-printed for readability):

```
{
  "contacts": foobar,  # <-- This is invalid! It's a string and needs to be quoted!
  "username": johndoe,
  "messageText": Hello World,  # <-- This is even more invalid!
  ...
}
```

I'd suggest to rely on PHP's [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) function to generate valid JSON output:

```
echo json_encode([
    "contacts" => $contactsSms,
    "username" => $username,
    "messageText" => $messageText,
    // etc.
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This was kind of a bug in alamoFire, that was fixed in release 3.1.1, see [pull #889](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/889), the fixed version works only if your REST like service returns response 204 (NO_RESPONSE) which is in theory the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Serialisation is the process of convert an object to a JSON string. So the problem is not the handling of your response, but that of your request.

Log the contents of your `parameters` dictionary, and check for nil values.